# increase value of global var inside function .each()

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var MidUpperArmCircumference = 0;
 var TricepsSkinfold = 0;

function checkMethod(method,parameters){
    $('#'+method+'_check').change(function() {
    if (this.checked == true) {
        $.each(parameters, function() {
            $('.'+this).css('color','blue');
            this++;    //HERE IS THE ERROR!
        });
    }
    });
}

var parametersMuscleArea = ['TricepsSkinfold', 'MidUpperArmCircumference'];
checkMethod('MidUpperArmMuscleArea',parametersMuscleArea);
});
```

How can I increase the variables `TricepsSkinfold` and `MidUpperArmCircumference` inside the `$.each` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the string, not the a reference to the local variable. You can't increase your variable by increasing the string. Also, you're trying to refer to a **local** variable by a name as given in a string. With local variables, this can only be done via `eval`, or by namespacing the variables.

This will work:

```
var ns = {
    MidUpperArmCircumference: 0,
    TricepsSkinfold: 0
};

function checkMethod(method,parameters){
    $('#'+method+'_check').change(function() {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $.each(parameters, function() {
                $('.'+this).css('color','blue');
                ns[this]++;    // <-- Fixed.
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *"`this` is an object reference"* Not always. In strict mode it will be a primitive if one set as the *thisArg*, which would be the case here. *"You can't "increase" an object."* Unless it's a Number object, or any object whose value can be converted *toNumber*, (in which case it will be coerced to a primitive).

Comment: @amnotiam Eh, that was rubbish indeed. I have changed that part (in relation with the question).

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just `++` **them**:

```
function checkMethod(method,parameters){
    $('#'+method+'_check').change(function() {
    if (this.checked == true) {
        $.each(parameters, function() {
            TricepsSkinfold++;
            MidUpperArmCircumference++;
            ...
            ...
            $('.'+this).css('color','blue'); // That looks wrong as well...
            // as "this" is the current item of the iteration. 
        });
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is more a question for me i suppose .... will this still work when the variables are declared inside of the `$(document).ready()` block ?

Comment: @ManseUK. Yes you can try it.

Comment: The rest of code is correct. Only the line tagged is the problem.
gdoron look the two last lines. The function will be call many times with diferents parameters. but thx.